# reactjs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When a user tried to redirect to the private route I am sending from: props.location so that after login user redirect back to the same link.

But when a user is going directly to sign in page it is showing

**Private route**

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/sign-in', state: { from: props.location} }} />
```

**Sign In page:**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.apiData !== this.props.apiData && nextProps.apiData !== false) {
      if(!(this.props.location.state.from.pathname)) {
       this.props.history.push(this.props.location.state.from.pathname)
      }
      else{
        if (this.props.location.length === 0) {
          this.props.history.push("/");
        }
        else{
          this.props.history.goBack();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It is giving me this error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined**

Comment: What are you getting your `nextProps`? Check it out.

Comment: show your full component, is it inside Route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.props.location.state` will only exist if component is mounted from `Redirect`, so you need to check if it exists first before accessing it:

```
if (this.props.location.state && !this.props.location.state.from.pathname) {
```